# Create 2D numpy array through nested loop

Tags: python

I would like to create a 2D array using nested loop. What is the problem with this code?

```
import numpy

b = np.array([])
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        b[i][j]=i+j

print(b)
```

Comment: you should accept the answer if the problem is gone @Reza

Answer (score 6):

The numpy array you are defining is not the right shape for the loop you are using. `b = np.array([])` gives you an array of shape `(0,)`

You can use something like `np.zeros` to define your 2D array.

```
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros((3,6))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        b[i][j]=i+j
print(b)
```

The output will be

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 0.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Another option is to make a 2D list, fill it up in for loops, and convert to numpy array later

```
import numpy as np

#2D array
b = [ [0 for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(3)]

#Fill up array with for loops
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        b[i][j]=i+j

#Convert to numpy array
print(np.array(b))
```

The output will be

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help @Reza Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I understand you asked how to do this with nested loops, so apologies if you don't find this useful. I'd just thought I'd share how I normally do this:

```
b = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
print(b)
```

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

the Proper way to do this is by following these four steps:

1 Initialize an empty array to store the results in

2  Create a for-loop looping over the lines/columns of the data array Inside the loop:

3  Do the computation

4  Append the result array

Comment: Except with numpy arrays, this may be costly as numpy arrays are immutable for the most part. I.e. appending the result into the array will create a new copy; and for this copy to persist, it needs to be assigned. Potentially, a lot of arrays will be created and thrown away. Nevertheless, your answer isn't entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random initialization trick with for loop for 3D.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)  # seed 

x1 = np.random.randint(10, size=3)  # One-dimensional array
x2 = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4))  # Two-dimensional array
x3 = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4, 5))  # Three-dimensional array
```

Later on you may use your magic for looping magic.

```
for _ in range(2):
    for __ in range(4):
        for ___ in range(5):
            x3[_][__][___]=_+__+___
```